# ASP.NET Select Method Using Entity framework Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, listview

I have ListView like this

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" ItemType="test.Project"  
     SelectMethod="ListView1_GetData" runat="server">
```

I am trying to set the select method to a stored procedure using EF. the select method like this

```
public IQueryable<Test.Project> ListView1_GetData()
{
    using (DREntities2 db=new DREntities2())
    {
        return db.GetLatestProjects().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I remove the `.AsQueryable()`, I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable

Here is the definition of the `GetLastestProjects_Result` as returned by `DREntities2 .GetLatestProjects()`:

```
public partial class GetLatestProjects_Result 
{ 
   public int ProjectID { get; set; } 
   public string Title { get; set; } 
   public string ShortDescr { get; set; } 
   public string Full_Descr { get; set; } 
   public int ProCatID { get; set; } 
   public bool Marquee { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Do you need the `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: without it i get error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Test.GetLatestProjects_Result>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Test.Project>

Comment: What is the `GetLatestProjects` method?

Comment: Yes, but what does it return? Can you show the method outline?

Comment: @DavidG: It returns a custom data type `GetLatestProjects_Result` generated by EF.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz How do you know that?

Comment: @DavidG: Its because of @AymanSharaf s comment above - `Cannot implicitly convert type  System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Test.GetLatestProjects_Result>`. EF creates a custom type (using Database First) for the return parameters from stored procedures.

Comment: Oh I see, so you need to convert from `GetLatestProjects_Result` to `Test.Project`?

Comment: @AymanSharaf: In future, please can you update the question directly instead of posting code samples in the comments. I have added them for you on this occasion. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidG yes if this is possible . or if there is any other solution

Comment: @AymanSharaf so something like this: `return db.GetLatestProjects().Select(p => new Test.Project { ProjectId = p.ProjectId, Title = p.Title .....};`

Comment: Stop posting code in the comments!

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Where else can we post them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure is returning `ObjectResult<Test.GetLatestProjects_Result>` and you are trying to convert it to `IQueryable<Test.Project>`. To do this you need to convert using the Linq `Select` method. Assuming `Test.GetLatestProjects_Result` and `Test.Project` have the same properties:

```
public IQueryable<Test.Project> ListView1_GetData()
{
    using (DREntities2 db=new DREntities2())
    {
        return db.GetLatestProjects().Select(p => new Test.Project
        {
            ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
            Title = p.Title,
            ShortDescr = p.ShortDescr,
            Full_Descr = p.Full_Descr,
            ProCatID = p.ProCatID,
            Marquee = p.Marquee
        }).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked fine. but i realised all i needed to do is to change the item type of el listview to the type of the stored procedure         ItemType="Test.GetLatestProjects_Result

Comment: Ayman, could you please post what changes you did in code behind as well?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game, but others may be able to do the following. Assuming that Test.Project is an EntityType, in the Model Browser change the return type of your stored procedure in the EF Model to Test.Project instead of the default GetLatestProjects_Result "complex type" that is created.

Then, in your query you can take the result to a typed list, then call AsQueryable on the result.

Here is an example that calls an SP named GetAllRequestsByWorkflowState which returns TravelRequestSummaryView entities:

```
private IQueryable<TravelRequestSummaryView> GetApprovalRequests(int approvalState)
{
    IQueryable<TravelRequestSummaryView> trsv = null;
    try
    {
        var res = db.GetAllRequestsByWorkflowState(approvalState)
            .ToList<TravelRequestSummaryView>();
        trsv = res.AsQueryable();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sqlTraceManager.WriteTraceIf(ex, User.Identity.Name);
    }
    return trsv;
}
```